# trying to send primary key value for editing data when button is pressed

Tags: php, html, mysql

Im trying to send a primary key value which corresponds to the button which has been pressed in a table of results from MySQL server. Each result has its own edit and delete buttons. I can create the button and the link to corresponding php page but I struggle with sending the value of the specific tuple which has been clicked. My code looks like

```
 try {
        $stmt->execute();
        $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
        if (!$results) { // check we have some results
            echo "No trainingCourses found <br />";
        } else { //generate table of trainingCourses
            print "<table>\n";
            echo "<th>Meeting ID</th><th>Title</th><th>Date</th><th>Link</th>\n";
            foreach ($results as $row) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row["trainingID"] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row["title"] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row["date"] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row["link"] . "</td>";
                echo "<td><a href='editTrainingCourse.php?id=".$row['trainingID']."'><strong>Edit</strong></a></td>";
                echo "<td><a href='deleteTrainingCourse.php?id=".$row['trainingID']."'><strong>Delete</strong></a></td>";

                echo "</tr>\n";
            }
            print "</table>\n";
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Query failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

    }
  catch (PDOException $e) {
    //$conn->rollBack();
    // If something raised an exception in our transaction block of statements,
    // roll back any work performed in the transaction
    exit('<p>Unable to complete transaction!</p>'.$e->getMessage());
     }
```

I think the answer lies with the

```
id=".$row['trainingID']
```

section but im just not sure how to handle that.

thanks for any and all help!

Comment: you can easily use Javascript to send values over AJAX to the PHP and handle the results

Comment: @user123_456 would it be easy to do that with this code? I've never really used AJAX before.

Comment: "I struggle with sending the value of the specific tuple which has been clicked" What does that even mean? If you view the HTML source,does the ID show up or not? What errors do you get?  I'm not understanding what the problem is.

Comment: @DigitalChris Sorry for any confusion, Im outputting a table of values from a database, each individual row(tuple) has its own buttons, edit and delete. When i view source the primary key does show up but im not  sure how to use that value on the page im redirecting to on the specific button click if that makes sense? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to create `editTrainingCourse.php` and `deleteTrainingCourse.php`.

In each of those, you will need to check for the existence of `$_GET['id']` which represents the `?id=xxx` found in the URL.

Verify that your id passed is indeed an integer, then use it:

```
if ( is_int($_GET['id']) ) {
    $trainingID = $_GET['id']);
}
else {
    die('bad ID given.');
}
```

Now perform your queries using `$trainingID`.